# How can I force Tailwind to include a color?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

In one of my React components, I receive a color palette name, and want to use it to change the colors in my component.

My attempt:

```
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    export interface LinkModel {
      to: string;
      label: string;
      color?: string;
    }
    
    export const Alink = ({ to, label, color = 'primary' }: LinkModel) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <Link to={to} className={'font-medium text-' + color + '-600 hover:text-' + color + '-500'}>
            {label}
          </Link>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

I noticed that if a combination (e.g. `text-primary-600`) isn't present anywhere in the app, it doesn't get bundled with the styles and my link isn't colored.

How can I force my additional styles to be bundled?

Comment: [Safelist](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes) classes you need

Comment: Second this, using the safelist is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that Tailwind does not detect dynamic class names.

One option is to add safelist classes to your Tailwind config. https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes

Another option is to include the full class string in your code.

Here is one possible way to do it by adding an object with all the combinations.

```
const variantsLookup = {
  primary: 'font-medium text-slate-600 hover:text-slate-500',
  blue: 'font-medium text-blue-600 hover:text-blue-500',
  red: 'font-medium text-red-600 hover:text-red-500',
}
```

And then the class can be added based on the `color` prop.

```
<Link to={to} className={`${variantsLookup[color]}`}>
  {label}
</Link>
```

Full credit to Simon for this idea.
https://www.protailwind.com/just-in-time-friendly-style-variants-in-tailwind-css-ui-components-part-1