# Tailwind, React: how to use conditional classes with extend theme?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I am making a project in React using Tailwind CSS. I have to use a specific color and add `border-{color}`, `bg-{color}`, and more styles depending on a prop. I'm using the approach below but it doesn't work. Can someone help me here?

**tailwindconfig.js**

```js
//tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
         colorA: '#ff6d00',
         colorB: '#33691e',
         colorC: '#ffd600',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**My components**

```
function Component() {
  const colors = ['colorA', 'colorB', 'colorC'];
  return (
    <>
      <div className="m-3 h-20 w-20 bg-colorC">colorC</div>
      {colors.map((color) => (
        <ComponentColor 
          key={color} type={color} /*or-> type={`bg-${color}`}*/ />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}

function ComponentColor({ type }) {
  const bgStyle = `bg-${type}`;
  // const bgStyle = type;
  return <div className={`m-3 h-20 w-20 ${bgStyle}`}>{type}</div>;
}
```

I understand that Tailwind is pre-rendered before it is loaded into the browser and only the classes used are bundled into the final style file. I can use a "safelist", but how could I handle the case where I have many colors and CSS properties?

```js
//tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
         colorA: '#ff6d00',
         colorB: '#33691e',
         colorC: '#ffd600',
      }
    }
  },
  safelist: ['bg-colorA', 'bg-colorB', ...],
}
```

Or there is a way to define the colors outside the Tailwind config and then call inside dynamically to generate the colors and safelist? Or perhaps some better method?

Comment: See this answer, it is very similar to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73669891/how-to-force-tailwind-to-include-a-color/73674903#73674903

Answer (score 1):

One quick solution is to pass the entire utility class to your `ComponentColor` component. This way, the class is not built dynamically and will be picked up by Tailwind without needing a safelist.

You can then strip the "bg-" if you need to display the color name.

For example:

```
function Component() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="m-3 h-20 w-20 bg-colorC">colorC</div>
      <ComponentColor colorClass="bg-colorA" />
      <ComponentColor colorClass="bg-colorB" />
      <ComponentColor colorClass="bg-colorC" />
    </>
  );
}

function ComponentColor({ colorClass }) {
  const type = colorClass.substring(3);
  return <div className={`m-3 h-20 w-20 ${colorClass}`}>{type}</div>;
}
```